# Hibernate acessing table in schema other than dbo results with Schema-validation: missing table

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, schema

I have a datasource that has two schemas: **dbo** and **example**.

I've created a table in dbo schema called **A**, and mapped it in hibernate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class ATable {
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

It runs without any errors as expected, I then proceeded to move the table to example schema with the following statement (runs successfully):

```
alter schema example transfer dbo.A
```

And changed the hibernate class as well:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A", schema = "example")
public class ATable {
    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

But upon running it, it throws the following exception, and exit the program.

```
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: A
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [A]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.performValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:727)
    at com.venditio.Application.main(Application.java:21)
```

I also tried using the following table annotation instead:

```
@Table(name = "example.A")
```

But it throws somewhat the same exception:

```
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: example.A
Sep 22, 2017 3:53:36 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl processGetTableResults
INFO: HHH000262: Table not found: example.A
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [example.A]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.performValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:727)
    at com.venditio.Application.main(Application.java:21)
```

It seems that I need to somehow configure hibernate to support the extra schema, but don't understand how.

Application:

```
public class Application {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        sessionFactory.openSession().close();
    }
}
```

And hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!--MSSQL-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/d1</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">a</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">1</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

        <!--Global-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="com.a.A" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, removing the following line from hibernate.cfg.xml did the trick

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
```

Comment: This is not a solution, this is only a workaround. Ideally you should always have validate set to enable JPA validate the schema on application launch, to avoid runtime exceptions.

Comment: I don't know why, but for me it works. But I have configured for 'none'.